# Why aren't my VS Code tokenColorCustomizations for brackets working?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm building my own VS Code theme and I came up with a problem. I've downloaded Darcula theme as a "base" for my theme and I'm using `setting.json` file to use `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` and `workbench.colorCustomizations` according to VS Code documentation.

I'm changing styles with `textMateRules`, but some of them simply aren't working.

In example:
1. This is the rule: [Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot80e.png)
2. And this is the output: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7BGo.png)

As you can see, the output should be #929293 but it's clearly not this colour, it's some weird blue colour instead of grey.

I've reinstalled VS Code (completely with scanning left-overs), disabled all extensions & reloaded the app etc. and nothing seems to work. It seems like the colour is being changed in the "code" (as inspector shows that color has changed) but the change is not visible. I tried on a "default" theme and output was the same.

Edit: I've fixed it, know-how in comment below.

Comment: I've fixed this. First of all, I've debugged VSC with Developert tools (Ctrl + Shift + P) -> Toggle Developer Tools https://imgur.com/a/69pmkXl and I've found that there is class "bracket highlighting" which overrides my token customisation. I've put option: `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false,` into settings.json and now my bracket styling is working just ok.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2):

As solved in the comments, this was due to the colour customizations being masked by the bracket pair colourization feature, which can be disabled with `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false` in the settings.